# How can I chain build pipelines in a blocking fashion?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to configure a Jenkins pipeline in the following fashion :

- Build A , B and C non blocking as they don't depend on each other 
  (but block  on the fact that A , B and C are still building)
- Build D

I tried to configure two pipelines :

- Pipeline 1 : Build A , B and C non blocking
- Pipeline 2 : Build D

But that did not work. A pipeline seems to  reports "Success" the moments a build starts which is not what I need.

Ideally I would like to stay within Jenkins UI instead of creating scripts to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **parallel** syntax. Found here: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel